# Is it ok to build an 64 bit ActiveX control with C# for enterprise application use

Tags: c#, c++, vb6, activex, atl

I am planning to build an 64 bit ActiveX control to be used in my web page. So my question is it OK to build it with C#? Will it be able to handle complex business logic? The reason why I ask this is that I am more familiar with C# than ATL.

Before raising this question, I searched all the related posts, they are all about how to build ActiveX with C#. However I would like to know if it will be a good choice or ATL will be more better?

By the way, the previous version of my ActiveX control is in 32 bit coded with VB6, but VB6 is impossible to build 64 bit ActiveX control.

I appreciate any of your suggestions and comments!

Regards,
Shuping

Comment: That's a pretty subjective question. If by "is it OK" you mean whether it is technically feasible, the answer would be yes. But we can hardly know any boundary conditions that may exist ... the limitations of C# should be well-known to you, so of course it would handle complex business logic. But you might want to look into porting the existing VB code to VB.NET ... it might be less effort - but of course I don't know the actual code, so it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Hi, I missed one thing that my ActiveX control will call some 64 bit COM DLLs(C++). So, compare to building the ActiveX control with ATL, does building it with C# or VB.NET have any drawbacks? such as .NET framework required on client machine? interop makes performance issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you're most comfortable with C#, why not build it in Silverlight? Will be a lot easier than building and deploying ActiveX controls.

Comment: +1. I'd seriously ask myself the question as to do I +really+ need to build this as an activex control at all. Surely there's a better alternative now for web deployments.

Comment: Hi JonoW, one more thing I missed is that my ActiveX control will call some third party COM DLLs(C++). actually, most functionalities come from the COM DLLs, my ActiveX control just a wrapper to expose minimal interface for web page javascript use. So, probably Silverlight is not able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

How about a Windows Forms app launched from Clickonce or Java web start? You cannot run a 64bit ActiveX from a 32bit IE.

Comment: Hi, my project is a web application running with web browsers (IE). the ActiveX control is embedded in the web page to show some graphic curves. currently I have a 32 bit version which can run on 32 bit IE. but now, we have the requirement to support 64 bit which will run on 64 bit IE.